# PyQt QTableView drag to reorder rows

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Hi I am trying to set up a playlist widget using QtTableView. The following code almost gets me there. But I have to click on the header itself. I would like to be able to click on any cell in the row and be able to drag it. Also the `setDropIndicatorShown` does not work. `model` has

```
class TestApp(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, model, parent = None):
        super(TestApp, self).__init__(parent)
        self.model = model

        table = QtGui.QTableView()
        table.setModel(self.model)
        table.setSortingEnabled(True)
        table.setDropIndicatorShown(True)
        table.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        table.setSelectionBehavior(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        table.horizontalHeader().setMovable(True)       
        table.horizontalHeader().setDragEnabled(True)
        table.horizontalHeader().setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)
        table.verticalHeader().setMovable(True)
        table.verticalHeader().setDragEnabled(True)
        table.verticalHeader().setDragDropMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.InternalMove)

class myModel(QtSql.QSqlTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(myModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setEditStrategy(QtSql.QSqlTableModel.OnFieldChange)

        self.setTable("my_table")
        self.select()
```